# Subset complicated dataset

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

I have a dataset:

```
x     y
A1  '*****'
A2  '123,0'
A3  '4557777'
A4  '8756784321675'
A5  'ЯРН'
A6  ''
A7  
A8
```

I want to remove all rows except those whose values in column y consist only of numbers or are empty(not '', but NA). So the desired output is this:

```
x     y
A3  '4557777'
A4  '8756784321675'
A7  
A8
```

How could I do that? As you see there is a value with cyrillic letters 'ЯРН'. Thats the most unclear part. With comma i tried this:

```
df[!grepl(",", df$y),]
```

But what to do with others

Comment: @IanCampbell empty is NA, '' is not an empty, its two apostrophes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following solution works even with cyrillic symbols, it takes advantage of the fact that to coerce a string that is not all numbers produces `NA`'s.

```
tmp <- gsub("'", "", df1$y)
i <- !is.na(suppressWarnings(as.numeric(tmp)))
j <- df1$y == "" | is.na(df1$y)
df1[i | j, ]
#   x               y
#3 A3       '4557777'
#4 A4 '8756784321675'
#7 A7                
#8 A8
```

**Data**

```
df1 <- read.table(text = "
x     y
A1  '*****'
A2  '123,0'
A3  '4557777'
A4  '8756784321675'
A5  'ЯРН'
A6  ''
A7  
A8
", header = TRUE, fill = TRUE, quote = "\"")
```

Comment: Might want to add a call to `as.character` in case someone comes years later with factors instead of character vectors.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an approach with base R:

You use the pattern `"'\\d+'"` which looks for a string that starts with `'`, has one or more digits and then ends with `'`.

```
df[grepl("'\\d+'",df$y) | is.na(df$y),]
   x             y
3 A3       '4557777'
4 A4 '8756784321675'
7 A7           <NA>
8 A8           <NA>
```

Comment: it removed also good rows like A3  '4557777' and A4  '8756784321675'

Comment: I didn't realize, as @Onyambu points out, that there were literal `'`s in your data. I think this should work.

Answer (score 1):

```
suppressWarnings(df[!is.na(as.numeric(df$y)) | is.na(df$y), ])
```

Comment: There will be warnings that are associated with this. You could suppress them

Comment: Although there are some issues with regard to the presence of `'`

Answer (score 1):

since your data seems to contain `'` you could do:

```
subset(df, grepl("^'?\\d+'?$",y) | is.na(y))
```

Comment: Good catch. I didn't realize the OP had actual `'`s.

Answer (score 0):

Using `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df %>%
   filter(str_detect(y, '^[0-9]+$')|is.na(y))
```